# enable LOCAL INFILE with PHP on Linux

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I'm having some issues loading some data into MySQL on Linux. I'm using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE. I can do it just fine on Mac OS X, specifically through the MySQL command line and a php script with a SQL query.

The issue arises when I'm on linux, it seems like LOAD DATA LOCAL is disabled per the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data-local.html) for security issues. To get around this problem, they give some possible workarounds such as using `--local-infile[=1]` on starting MySQL, but what am I suppose to do if I'm using PHP?

Specifically, in the command line, I get the error:

```
ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
```

I'm also using version:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.41, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you doing this via PHP script or PHPCLI?

Answer (score 0):

You can set it from an sql statement, assuming you have the correct permissions to change global variables;

```
SET GLOBAL local_infile = 'ON';
```

Check to see if the changes have taken effect;

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
```